# Can't use CSS to define cursor style

Tags: html, css

In the CSS file, I define:

```
td.sorting{cursor: pointer}
```

Then in the html file:

```
<table>
<tr>
<!-- some other <td> -->   
<td id="sortByOrderId" onclick="sort(this);" class="sorting">Order ID</td>
<!-- some other <td> -->  
</tr>
</table>
```

But this doesn't work. However, if I change it like the following, it works:

```
<td id="sortByOrderId" onclick="sort(this);" style="cursor: pointer">Order ID</td>
```

I can use other CSS styles without any problem, like:

```
<td id="sortByOrderId" onclick="sort(this);"  class="numberTitle">Order ID</td>
```

I don't understand why. Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `;` after the style? Its working in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/eeAhn/

Comment: In which browser do you have that problem?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/n6q65/ Use the CSS inspector to find out what else is setting the cursor and overriding your selector.

Comment: @Filly - `element.class` has been supported by all browsers that support CSS selectors.

Comment: Is the `;` optional? In all browsers?

Comment: @KevinBowersox - Yes. The semicolon is optional for the last property setting in the list.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Your hunch (being overridden) makes sense, since the inline style gets the highest precedence.  Good thinking!

Comment: I'm working on Safari and Chrome. I've tried adding ; and use .sorting instead of td.sorting. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: This is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/n6q65/1/

Comment: When all else fails, use `!important`

Comment: @StephenKong Are you familiar with the inspector Jared is referring to?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think maybe it's overridden. But where is the CSS inspector? Is it a tool? Sorry for my fool.

Comment: @KevinBowersox No, that's what I want to ask about. Where can I get it please?

Comment: In Chrome, right click the content in the table cell and select `Inspect element`.  Got it?

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Oh. I've been using Safari all the time. Never know this thing. Cool. Thank you so much.

Comment: @StephenKong Glad I could help, you should see that there is a style taking precedence over the one you have defined.

Comment: @nullability - No, sprinkling `important` around whenever something doesn't seem to work is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you very body. Problem solved. There was a conflict.